# In Xpath how do I check the time difference in 2 dateTimes

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

Say I have 2 dateTime elements in XML:

```
<effectivedate>2018-08-28 15:45:00</effectivedate>
<startdate>2018-08-28 15:44:00</startdate>
```

I can subtract the 2 to get the difference like so:

```
xs:dateTime(replace(//effectivedate," ","T")) - xs:dateTime(replace(//startdate," ","T"))
```

but this returns PT1M. How can I use this to check if the time difference is less than 5 minutes?

Comment: Apologies about the formatting, but hopefully you get what I'm asking for!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. Either convert the duration to a number (of minutes, say) by dividing by a constant duration and then compare with a number:

```
$duration div xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1M') lt 5
```

or subtract two durations directly:

```
$duration lt xs:dayTimeDuration('PT5M')
```